# Laravel get second level relations

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, orm, database-relations

I have three database tables:

```
+------+-----------+---------------------+
| user | user_type | user_type_relations |
+------+-----------+---------------------+
```

Each user can have many types, but one user type can only have one user. To store this relation, I use a third relationship table, with the following structure:

```
+---------------------+
| user_type_relations |
+---------------------+
| id                  |
| user_id             |
| user_type_id        |
+---------------------+
```

I have defined the relations in my models like so:

`User` model:

```
public function userTypeRelations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('UserTypeRelations', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
```

`UserType` model:

```
public function userTypeRelation()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('UserTypeRelations', 'user_type_id', 'id');
    }
```

`UserTypeRelations` model:

```
 public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('User', 'id', 'user_id');
    }

    public function userType()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('UserType', 'id', 'user_type_id');
    }
```

And this is how I try to access the user type of a specific user in my controller, before passing it to a view:

```
$users = User::with('userTypeRelations')->with('userType')->orderBy($order)->where('status', 'active')->paginate(10);
```

I thought that first I get the relation table's value, and from that I'll easily get the User Type of each User, but I get the following error:

```
BadMethodCallException

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::userType()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10):

You can eager load <strike>multiple</strike> nested relations to a model by passing them both to a single call to `with`:

```
User::with('userTypeRelations.userType') ...
```

[Source](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading)

Comment: Thanks, didn't know this. Sorry if I wasn't clear, but what I want to do is to first get the userTypeRelation, and from the ID that comes back, get the user type. So this is why I called it _second level_ (not sure if the term is correct).

Comment: + I modified my code with a single call to `with`, but I still get the same error

Comment: Ok I updated the code.  I believe in the Laravel docs they're calling these _nested_ relationships.  See if that works for you.

Answer (score 3):

I believe your relationships are wrong.  This is actually a many to many relationship which means you can get rid of your `UserTypeRelations` all together.

So with that said, delete `UserTypeRelations.php` and then pretend that relation no longer exists.  Laravel will handle that table for you.

Then in your user model, create the function...

```
public function types()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('UserType', 'user_type_relations','user_type_id', 'user_id');
}
```

And in your UserType model add the function...

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'user_type_relations', 'user_id', 'user_type_id');
}
```

Now it's no longer a nested relation.

```
$user = User::with('types')->find($id);
foreach($user->types as $type) {
    echo $type;
}
```

Comment: Nice catch, I believe this is better for OP

Comment: Yep from the information given the OP is trying to manually create the pivot table but Laravel wants to do this automatically